# getTimezoneOffset() returns a different value on ios than all other platforms

Tags: javascript, ios, timezone-offset

The issue is that JavaScript behaves unpredictably when polling for the current timezone offset. The expected result for my timezone is

```
> new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
-60
```

This is the result when run on

- Samsung Galaxy Tab A (Android 7.0)
- Windows 10 (Firefox, Chrome, Edge)
- OSx 10.14 (Safari, Chrome)
- Ubuntu 18.04 (Firefox, Chrome)

On iOS however, the following occurs:

```
> new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
-120
```

This has been tested with

- Safari on iOS on both iOS 11.0.2 and 12.1.1 (latest as of typing)
- Chrome 71.0.3578.89 iOS 11.0.2 and 12.1.1

If the timezone is changed to a timezone that does not use Daylight Savings Time, however, like that of Marocco, the `getTimezoneOffset()` returns the same as on other platforms. Does anyone have any insight into this?

**Edit: clarification**

I tried running with the system time set to an arbitrary date within DST (7th of January 2019) and two dates within summertime (17th of May 2019 and 12th of August 2018) and the result was always the same. In addition to using my own timezone (GMT+1 Oslo), I also tried GMT+0 (London) and GMT+2 (Athens) with the same results. Only when set to GMT+1 (Marrakesh) did I see any difference in result.

Comment: Did you check the date & time setting on the iOS device? For me it does work properly with the same ios version. https://codepen.io/quic5/pen/ZVNaVZ

Comment: I think maybe this is a Daylight Saving Time problem. You can check your client's timezone, and your server's timezone. (web server or SQL Server)

Comment: @Philipp yes, I checked with both automatic and manually setting the timezone

Comment: Which time zone setting(s) did it *fail* with? Were you running the code on the same date in both cases? Recently, or on another date?

Comment: @MattJohnson I have updated the question with some clarification around which timezones I tested. In all cases I ran the same code; `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`

Comment: For anyone having struggles with similar problems I can recommend https://momentjs.com/ which solved the issue I was having with this.

Comment: Moment uses that very same function internally... 0__o

Comment: Is it possible that your results are skewed because perhaps the browser app isn't picking up the time zone change immediately?  Try killing the app before testing after making the changes, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: My issue was not the timezone offset directly, but somewhat related and specific to the app I was debugging. Momentjs helped me fix that issue, I see now that was unclear in my comment. The timezone offset was something I discovered while hunting for the cause of that bug. To answer your question: the bug persisted across rebooting both iPads used for testing